# ORA-02437: cannot validate <name> - primary key violated

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  MY_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  COLUMN_1 NUMBER,
  COLUMN_2 NUMBER
);
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FOO PRIMARY KEY (MY_ID);
```

at a later point, when executing the following sql, I get an error:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY DROP INDEX;
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FOO PRIMARY KEY (MY_ID) 

ORA-02437: cannot validate PK_FOO - primary key violated
```

My table only contains 3 entries all with a different primary key which is also not null.
Anyone has an idea what this could be?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Could you post your CREATE TABLE / INSERTS statements so that we can reproduce your case ?

Answer (score 7):

> My table only contains 3 entries all with a different primary key which is also not null.

You must forgive a certain amount of scepticism on our part.  Because that error definitely indicates a duplicate value.

What you need to do is use the `exceptions` clause.  This will show you the ROWIDs of the  records which are violating your constraint.  You may need to create the target table: by default the script creates a table called EXCEPTIONS:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FOO PRIMARY KEY (MY_ID);
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FOO PRIMARY KEY (MY_ID)
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02437: cannot validate (APC.PK_FOO) - primary key violated


SQL> @%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\utlexpt1.sql

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FOO PRIMARY KEY (MY_ID)
  2  exceptions into exceptions
  3  /
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FOO PRIMARY KEY (MY_ID)
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02437: cannot validate (APC.PK_FOO) - primary key violated


SQL> select * from exceptions
  2  /

ROW_ID             OWNER TABLE_NAME CONSTRAINT
------             ----- ---------- ----------
AABQXcAAEAAAXUPAAD APC   MY_TABLE   PK_FOO        
AABQXcAAEAAAXUPAAB APC   MY_TABLE   PK_FOO        

SQL>
```

**Edit**

You need to figure out what is different between your install code and the simplification you posted here.  The chances are you have one or more `INSERT` statements which are accidentally executed more than once while the constraint is not in force.   Adding the `EXCEPTIONS INTO` clause to your code might help you track it down.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tried it... Unfortunately I could not reproduce the problem when simply executing these few sql snippets. The error happens only as part of a big installation procedure where these lines get executed.

Answer (score 2):

from [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02437.php)

> Cause:    You tried to tried to enable a
>   primary key constraint, but the
>   columns in the primary key either
>   contained NULL values or duplicates..

Comment: As I wrote before... the table contains 3 *different*, *non-null* values for the primary key.

Comment: may I ask, what are those primary-key values?

Comment: Here's my table definition:

Column Name   Data Type  Nullable  Column Id  PK
MY_ID       NUMBER     No                1   1
COLUMN_2      NUMBER     Yes               2 
COLUMN_3      NUMBER     Yes               3

Comment: Grrr... formatting does not work in here :-(
All columns are defined as number, MY_ID is defined as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The maim reason of violation of primary ki is the atrrbute you making is nullable or you have some dupliactes in table for that id or attribute

```
create table client_master
(
client_no varchar2(6),
client_name varchar2(20),
city varchar2(25),
state varchar2(15),
pin number(6),
balance_due number(10,2));
```

for e.g,
after inserting values
0008    Mukul   NYCT    NYC 199560  2500

0006    Rukmini bombay  maharastra  100001  0

0007    Krishna mathura up  900050  100000

0008    Mukul   NYCT    NYC 199560  2500

or your id is nullable

so just MODIFY THE ATTRIBUTE is and set to NOT NULL
also remove duplicates if any

```
DELETE client_master  
WHERE rowid NOT IN 
  (SELECT MAX(rowid)  
FROM client_master
GROUP BY client_no,client_name,city,state,pin,balance_due);
```

then you we will be able to add primary key to client _no

Answer (score 0):

Are 2 primary keys identical?

This error is usually thrown when you try to create/enable a primary key on a table

Comment: As I wrote before... the table contains 3 *different*, *non-null* values for the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm upvoting APC's answer, but since you seem to have some problems implementing it, could you just post the results of this query:

```
select my_id, count(*) from my_table group by my_id having count(*) >1
```

This will give us (and you) some idea of the problematic keys.

Comment: select my_id, count(*) from my_table group by my_id having count(*) > 1 doesn't return any rows.

select my_id, count(*) from my_table group by my_id returns 3 rows with 3 different id's and count = 1.

Comment: OK - I see now with the additional comments that this is happening as part of a more involved process - I thought you would have access to the table with the offending rows prior to the constraint being applied.

Answer (score 0):

**There may be duplicate values**

*please 1st run following sql command*

```
SELECT MENU_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY MENU_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

*after you can run ALTER TABLE commands*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Solution was to truncate (empty) the table first.
Then you can add the constraint.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35299664)